# Couchdb query for values calculated from key input

Tags: couchdb

suppose i have the following data in my database:

```
[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[3,1]...
```

were the numbers represent the a and b values of the formula a*x+b

what i now want is a query that returns the difference to a given point x,y.

for example: the point [2,6] is given. i want my query to return

```
[1,2] = -2 (1*2+2=4  4-6=-2)
[2,1] = -1 (2*2+1=5  5-6=-1)
[1,3] = -1 (1*2+3=5  4-6=-1)
[3,1] =  1 (3*2+1=7  7-6=-1)
```

I know how to do this in SQL but the data is already in a couchdb. I'm quite new to the NoSQL world and was wondering if something like this would be possible in couchdb.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to use the standard MapReduce functionality of CouchDB.
Map is function you put in a view, which finds your data. You can have various criteria how to locate the docs you need. Next, if you specify so in the query with reduce=true, a reduce function is executed on each document that matched the map condition. You can use JavaScript to perform various operations on the document's values. 
In your  case, the map can look something like this:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.a && doc.b) {
        emit(doc._id,[doc.a, doc.b]);
    }
}
```

then, the reduce gets called, like this:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
    var res;
   //do something with values...
   return res;
}
```

In your case `keys` will be list of document ID's and `values` will be the array of your a & b fields.

When you call the MapReduce (depending what method you use to access the DB), you should specify `reduce=true`.

Good resources on MapReduce (and on Views, Sorting and List funtions) are:

http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html
http://www.slideshare.net/okurow/couchdb-mapreduce-13321353

Another way to go is to use a list function on the Map result, if you want to output the result in HTML. A good reason to use List function is that you can pass arguments to it with querystring, in your case it may be the point for which you want to calculate distances.

For detailed description on List functions, have a look here:
http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem i have with map reduce is that i don't have access to the startkey, endkey or key. So an important Part of the calculation is missing namely the x value in the formula above.  Is the list function any faster than fetching all docs and perform the search in .. say... node.js for example? anyways i'll habe a look at list, thanks!

Comment: Of course you can use node.js. As for speed, I can only guess that running this in Couch DB and returning the results only will be faster than getting all docs in node.js and calculating there. Depends on the number of docs and how big they are - do they have only these two values, or also additional data.

Comment: Thats only a simplyfied example, the mathematical expression is more complex in real life(14 variables)... But there are only a few hundred docs. the size oft the documents can be reduced to only a few needed fields with a simple map function... I will do some performance tests for both methods.  Anyway, thanks for your help!